# "Responsive" horizontally list items?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I'm currently working on my website and have some issues with the navigation bar. I would like to have the first list-item on the left, everything else should stay on the right. (See the attached image)

```
<li>Some Text</li>
<li>About</li>
<li>Work</li>
<li>Contact</li>
<li>Etc.</li>
```

I can now try some stupid CSS like

```
li:first-child:
padding-right:300px;
```

but that's definitely the wrong way to go. Could anyone provide a smarter, more modern solution, that works responsive/fluid? Thanks.

Comment: i don't think this is possible using only 1 list

Comment: What is a better solution?

Comment: The way i'd do it is use reactJS and create the menu in the shadowDOM. That way you can do some logic on page load to get the URL and depending on which one move the appropriate Item from say a menuArray into it's own floated span.

Comment: Just look at the way people implement hamburger icons for mobile websites, you'll have to do something similar to that.

Comment: Thanks, but isn't there a smarter solution for people like me who don

Comment: Depends, you could do it in HTML / css but it could get tiresome depending on how many pages you have

Comment: It also means if you need to change your menu you only have to alter the menuArray once in the javscript file, rather then go through all your HTML files and changing it in each one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't do it that way. You make one wrapper div and set overflow hidden to it, then inside it put one `<a>` that you float to left, and ul that you float to right like this.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <a class="logo">logo</a>

  <ul class="main-nav">
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And the css would be:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}

 .logo {
   float: left;
 }

 .main-nav {
   float: right;
 }

 .main-nav li {
   display: inline-block;
 }
```

Hope this helped :)